# configurar htaccess para acessar de dentro de outras pastas o sistema

Tags: php

tenho o seguinte domínio `meusite.com.br` dentro do diretorio raiz tenho a pasta "suporte" porém quando digito no navegador `meusite.com.br/suporte` ele me retorna uma pagina em branco. Acredito que este erro é por causa do meu htaccess. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Ele está da seguinte forma:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(api)/
RewriteRule .* index.php [PT,L]
```

Dentro da pasta api tenho outro htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [PT,L]
```

O sistema roda perfeitamente se eu coloco ele na pasta raiz, porém não é isso que eu quero, pois lá, já está o meu site.

Comment: Essa página em branco seria o `index.php`?

Comment: tenta usar `Allow from all`

Comment: na sua pasta de suporte por acaso tem algum arquivo `index.html`?